# Supreme adding to cart with Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

So I'm currently trying to cart an item on supreme through requests. After posting the carting request I don't get any errors but just that it didn't work as a response.

```
#imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#constants
baseurl = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/"
product_category = ""
size = ["Medium"]
product_keywords = ["Supreme®/The North Face® Steep Tech Fleece Pant"]
product_style = ["Brown"]


#functions

def carting(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(baseurl+url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    name = soup.find("h1", {"itemprop" : "name"}).text
    style = soup.find("p", {"itemprop" : "model"}).text
    for keyword in product_keywords:
        if keyword in name:
            for keyword in product_style:
                if keyword in style:
                    print("Product Found! Adding to cart...")
                    form = soup.find("form", {"id" : "cart-add"})
                    payload = {
                        "utf8" : "✓",
                        "authenticity_token" : form.find("input", {"name" : "authenticity_token"})["value"],
                        "style" : form.find("input", {"name" : "style"})["value"],
                        "size" :  "92001",           #form.find("select", {"id" : "size"})["value"]  Need to rework getting Size through Keyword
                        "qty" : "1"
                    }
                    headers = {
                        "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                        "origin" : "https://www.supremenewyork.com",
                        "referer" : baseurl + url,
                        "path" : form["action"],
                        'Host': 'www.supremenewyork.com',                                                                                                                     
                        'Accept': 'application/json',                                                                                                                             
                        'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',                                                                                                                                   
                        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',                                                                                                                               
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',                                                                                                                                
                        'Accept-Language': 'en-us',                                                                                                                                        
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                                            
                        'Origin': 'http://www.supremenewyork.com',                                                                                                                
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    }
                    response = session.post(baseurl+form["action"], data=payload)
                    
                    print(response.text)
                    
                    return(session)

carting("/shop/pants/mj1czv0pa/jcyp91a8w")
```

The answer I get  printed is

```
Product Found! Adding to cart...
{"cart":[],"success":false}
```

I wondered if I just have to gamble on which of all the headers I have to include so it works since maybe the site wants to have a certain or maybe all headers included that would be sent manually.
Help appreciated!